# I Get Image File Upload Error On My Django Project

Tags: python, django

so I did this and it works perfectly offline but online keeps giving 404.

Now the issue is the file upload because online I debugged by removing the file upload input field and the path URL works fine.

So my question is why is the file upload causing this problem and how can I fix it.

[image: error message]

**Main URL**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('UserAccount.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('Dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', include('Admin.urls')),
    path('tester/', include('Tester.urls')),
    path('paystack', views.paystack, name='paystack'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Admin URL**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.admin, name='admin'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashbaord'),
    path('create-category', views.category, name='category'),
    path('create-category/<id>', views.category, name='category'),
    path('upload-document', views.upload, name='upload-document'),
    path('upload-document/<id>', views.upload, name='upload-document'),
    path('upload-document/<setup>/<id>', views.upload, name='upload-document')
]
```

**FORM**

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="upload-document" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

                  {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3"></div>

                    {% if messages %}

                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

                      {% for message in messages %}

                      {{ message }}

                      {% endfor %}

                    </div>

                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="validationCustom01">Upload Document</label>

                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="document" placeholder="Upload document" required>

                        <div class="invalid-feedback">

                            Please upload document.

                          </div>

                         <div class="valid-feedback">

                          Looks good!

                        </div> 

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="validationCustom01">Document Name</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="document-name" placeholder="Enter document name" required>

                        <div class="invalid-feedback">

                            Please enter document name.

                          </div>

                        <!-- <div class="valid-feedback">

                          Looks good!

                        </div> -->

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                      <label for="validationCustom01">Document Price</label>

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="document-price" placeholder="Enter document price" required>

                      <div class="invalid-feedback">

                          Please enter document price.

                        </div>

                      <!-- <div class="valid-feedback">

                        Looks good!

                      </div> -->

                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select a category</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="category" required>
                        {% for cat in category %}
                        <option value="{{cat.category_name}}">{{cat.category_name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>

                      <div class="invalid-feedback">

                        Please select a category.

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="validationCustom01">Document Slug</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="document-slug" placeholder="Enter document slug">


                        <!-- <div class="valid-feedback">

                          Looks good!

                        </div> -->

                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="validationCustom01">Document Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="document-description" rows="6" placeholder="Enter document description"></textarea>

                        <!-- <div class="valid-feedback">

                          Looks good!

                        </div> -->

                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-red btn-block">UPLOAD</button>
                   
                  </form>
```